# GCP cloud composer PythonOperator hanging

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am using cloud composer 2.0.23 (airflow 2.2.5)
My job is a gen2 cloud function, reading\writing data in BQ. And I send HTTP requests in the operator.

I notice that if I have jobs with execution time more than 10~15min, even if the cloud function finished successfully, the status shown on airflow never updates.

[update1]
Cloud function info:
[image]

[image]

Airflow job status:
[image]
It should be "success".

[update2]
code snippet in my DAG.py

```py
def call_cloud_function_endpoint(gcf_url, **kwargs):
    """Call Cloud Function's endpoint and record time used in BigQuery"""

    # Set timer for recording function execution time
    start = pendulum.now(tz='Asia/Taipei')

    # This parts calls Cloud Function, which has 'Requir Authentication' enabled'
    auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, gcf_url)

    if ('params' in kwargs) and kwargs['params']:
        p_list=[]
        for k in kwargs['params']:
            p_list.append(f"{k}={kwargs['params'][k]}") 
        gcf_url = f"{gcf_url}?{'&'.join(p_list)}"

    print(f'send request: {gcf_url}')

    req = urllib.request.Request(gcf_url)
    req.add_header('Authorization', f'Bearer {id_token}')
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

    # Cloud Function returns a response by json.dump
    # Use json.loads to turn response into dict type
    result = json.loads(response)

    # Timer for finished Execution 
    end = pendulum.now(tz='Asia/Taipei')

    # Create execution record and write to BigQuery
    gcf_function_name = gcf_url.split('/')[-1]
    execution_result = [{ # depends on your response body
                        'date': start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                        'time': start.format('HH:mm:ss'),
                        'task_name': gcf_function_name,
                        'runtime': end.diff(start).in_seconds(), 
                        'status': result['status'], 
                        'message': result['message'],
                        'output_num': result['output_num']
                        }]

    write_to_bq(TABLE_ID, execution_result)

    # Cloud Function response contains 
    # 'status': indicate execution result by 'success' or 'failed'
    # 'message': could be records the cloud function has output or error message
    if result['status'] == 'failed':
        raise AirflowFailException(result['message'])
    return result['message']


with DAG(
    dag_id='DAG_Demo',
    start_date= TODAY,
    schedule_interval=None,  # schedule_interval=None if the DAG is manually triggered
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args,
    tags=['Demo']
) as dag:

    # All Tasks
    my_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='my_task', 
        python_callable=call_cloud_function_endpoint, 
        op_kwargs={
            'gcf_url': config['gcf_endpoint']['my_task']['url'],
            'params': config['gcf_endpoint']['my_task']['params'],
            }
    )
```

And the logic of my cloud function (GEN2)

```py
import json
import time
import functions_framework

@functions_framework.http
def sleep_900_sec(request):
    
    time.sleep(900)
    data = {"status": "success", "message": "Successfully Run", "output_num": 3}
    return json.dumps(data)
```

Maybe I should not use PythonOperator? (use HTTPOperator? BashOperator? or else)
Or, did I miss some setting in the Airflow/cloud function configuration?

---

Any suggestion is appreciated

Thanks in prior

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of the status?

Comment: @PoalaAstrid please check my updates, thanks!

Comment: All I want to do is sending request to a cloud function API, then process the respose

Comment: Hi, I was replicating your case and it worked but I want to know how big is the data you're  reading/writing and how many rows it has?

Comment: This case is a 'sleeping' job, do nothing. In my tests, if the execution time exceeds certain amount of time. Airflow will never update the task status.
Maybe it is because of HTTPoperator? different regions between cloud function&composer? Or something else?

Comment: Can you check the timeout limit of your Cloud Function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Cloud Composer likely has a firewall rule that kills idle TCP connections. (e.g. long-running HTTP requests) Set TCP Keep-alive flags to prevent this.

I solved a similar problem by setting TCP Keep-alive flags in Python. There is a [in-depth explanation](https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/21365#discussioncomment-3120923) of this issue focussing on Airflow's internal SimpleHttpOperator, but it's entirely transferable for PythonOperators that issue any HTTP request.

I resolved this issue by setting TCP Keep-alive flags for Python's `urllib3` `HTTPConnection.default_socket_options`. As suggested in this [blog post comment](https://blog.panagiks.com/2019/05/python-tcp-keepalive-on-http-request.html?showComment=1662658242095#c9201662618171124390)

I would recommend changing your code as follows:

```
def call_cloud_function_endpoint(gcf_url, **kwargs):
  import socket
  from urllib3.connection import HTTPConnection

  HTTPConnection.default_socket_options += [
      (socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1),
      (socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 60),
      (socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 60),
      (socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPCNT, 100),
  ]
  """Call Cloud Function's endpoint and record time used in BigQuery"""
  # Set timer for recording function execution time
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll do some tests and tell you the result

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated your case with a large-sized public dataset, and it was stuck in "up for retry" or "running" in Airflow. So I changed the `Memory allocated` and `Timeout` in Cloud Functions configuration. Try to increase both but I set Timeout into maximum.

[image]

It worked for me.

This image is the logs for Airflow.
[image: airflow]

This is for Cloud Function.

[image: cloud-function]

Let me know if this can help or if not, we can still figure out the solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi, please check my updates. In my test, it is not the matter of CPU\MEM, it is about "time". Thank you!